# Make Chrome New Tab Totally Blank

Tags: google-chrome

I want to open a tab and nothing but a tab. So far, I have used [New Tab Redirect!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) and specified a blank redirect URL, which becomes `about:blank`. But when I press CMD/CTRL + T it gives focus to the location bar but puts the cursor after `about:blank`. Is there a way to either clear `about:blank` entirely or select all the text, so I can start typing straight away and not have to CMD/CTRL + A and backspace/delete?

EDIT:

I tried :

```
html {
    display: none !important;
}
```

With the [stylish plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) for URL `chrome://newtab` but it didn't work.

Comment: 'at startup' is _not_ synonymous to 'whenever I open a new tab'. Yet, the [solution below](https://superuser.com/a/447362/75914) does the job.

Answer (score 5):

There's the "Blank New Tab" extension:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfdloiaebhgmjpaclbbodcmlmppkakjh

Should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Chrome often give me freezing look when he is trying to open a new not-so-blank tab, which is way too often. This plugin helps me!

Comment: Blank New Tab Page URL has changed to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jaadjnlkjnhohljficgoddcjmndjfdmi (I'd edit but the edit queue is full)

Answer (score 4):

When you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it will select the whole location bar.

**The backspace key is not required**, when text is selected and you start to type the text will disappear.

Comment: Ah I overlooked that, cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy getting your hands dirty with a bit of CSS, then I'd suggest using [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to alter the default tab page - it leaves the location bar blank.

Comment: See my update. It didn't work, am I specifying the wrong URL?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Settings > On startup  > Open a specific page or set of pages. Set pages (Click and type below line)

```
display:none
```

Note : Make sure no spaces are copied before and after the above line.

Comment: This is nice for the starting page but it would be great if we could use it for all new tabs.