# How to show a blank page in "New Tab" within Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, extension

I am annoyed by the thumbnails that are shown when opening a new tab in Google Chrome. I want to see a blank page. How to do that?

Comment: Go to chrome settings -> search -> mange search engine . Close all the URL in Default search settings.

Comment: 'at startup' is _not_ synonymous to 'whenever I open a new tab'. (maybe it _was_ essentially the same setting in _elder_ chrome versions..) [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/447362/75914) does the job (and [that question](https://superuser.com/q/383909/75914) indeed is a duplicate, also asking about new tabs being blank...).

Answer (score 6):

As for the newer Versions, the browser settings are not reachable through chrome-internal://... etc., here is a pretty simple solution:

1. Install [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/related?hl=en) extension for Google Chrome
2. Set the redirect page in the extension options to "about:blank" or whatever you like (see image below)

[image]

Comment: Variant with minimal resource impact I've just posted here: http://superuser.com/a/1046794/120138

Comment: I find [Blank New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jonikckfpolfcdcgdficelkfffkloemh?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) slightly easier to use...

Comment: Empty New Tab Page supports OS-based dark mode! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij/related?hl=en-US

Comment: Blank New Tab Page extension does not allow to use bookmarklets, unlike about:blank.

Comment: @FrankN Your link is now 404. I think the [Blank New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jaadjnlkjnhohljficgoddcjmndjfdmi) URL has changed - can you confirm if that's the same one you were link to?

Comment: @icc97 Yes, the one I picket seems gone. But there are still [plenty to choose from](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij/related) on the official chrome store.

Comment: @FrankN the link I posted was to what looks like the same extension, just a different URL - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jaadjnlkjnhohljficgoddcjmndjfdmi